# почему ключ не работает, помогите пожалуйста решить, не могу понять

Tags: php, массивы, php7

```
for ($c = 2; $c <= 100; $c++) {
for($i = 2; $i < $c; $i++) {    
if ($c % $i == 0) continue 2;
}
    $arr=[$c];      
    foreach($arr as $k => $value){          
          echo $value.'- '."Это простое число №".' '.$k.'<br>';
     }      
    }
```

Comment: Вы каждый раз создаёте новый массив из одного элемента

Comment: Ну а как решить данную проблему

Comment: `Ну а как решить данную проблему` - не создавать каждый раз новый массив из одного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

По видимому, $arr должен быть массивом, но вы перезаписываете эту переменную на каждой итерации.

```
for ($c = 2; $c <= 100; $c++) {
    for ($i = 2; $i < $c; $i++) {
        if ($c % $i == 0) continue 2;
    }
    $arr[] = $c;
}
foreach ($arr as $k => $value) {
    echo $value . '- ' . "Это простое число №" . ' ' . $k . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое.